# How to pass the object given in the input data in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

```js
let payload = [{
  “OfficeCode”: “xyz”,
  “Tsb_data” : [{ 
      “Tsb_acc” : “1234”,
      “Tsb_amt” : “”
    }]
}]


var form = document.createElement(“form”)
form.setAttribute(“method”,”post”)
form.setAttribute(“action”, url)
var input_data = document.createElement(‘input’)
input_data.type=hidden
input_data.name=input_data
input_data.value = payload
```

How to pass the payload value here ??
Once when I am passing the `payload` in the `input_data.value` it shows like its `[object object]`. Please help me to pass it as a value.. thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see any react code in the snippet you've shared. One way to use that data in the input field would be to stringify it. `input_data.value = JSON.stringify(payload)`